# Storing a list of key value pairs in a url parameter, javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-parameters

Assuming `www.mydomain.com?param1=example` as an example.

What is the best way to store a second parameter that is a list of key value pairs?  At the minute I use `&param2=key|value,key|value`.  I separate the key from the value using a vertical line, and the pairing with a comma, everything after the equals is encoded using `encodeURIComponent()`.  This works fine.

However, the user has control of the value... And as sensible human beings we all know that the first thing the user will probably do is stick a vertical bar or a comma as one of the values breaking my parameter parser.  Is there a better way to do this?  I've seen PHP users talking about storing associated arrays in urls but I'm looking for a *pure javascript solution*.

Comment: You know, you can use arrays as GET parameters: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/5808.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP (and other server-side languages) support passing arrays in the query string.

```
www.mydomain.com?param1=example&param2[key1]=value1&param2[key2]=value2
```

PHP will parse the GET string as such:

```
array(2) {
  ["param1"]=>
  string(7) "example"
  ["param2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key1"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    ["key2"]=>
    string(6) "value2"
  }
}
```

If you don't pass keys, it will be become a numeric array:

```
www.mydomain.com?param1=example&param2[]=value1&param2[]=value2
```

Will be parsed as:

```
array(2) {
  ["param1"]=>
  string(7) "example"
  ["param2"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "value2"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: You can also parse the query string in JavaScript.

Here is a simple jQuery plugin I made:

```
$.parseQuery = function(str) {
    var ret = {};
    $.each(str.split("&"), function() {
        var data = this.split('='),
            name = decodeURIComponent(data.shift()),
            val = decodeURIComponent(data.join("=")).replace('+', ' '),
            nameVal = name.match(/(.*)\[(.*)\]/);

        if (nameVal === null) {
            ret[name] = val;
        }
        else {
            name = nameVal[1];
            nameVal = nameVal[2];
            if (!ret[name]) {
                ret[name] = nameVal ? {} : [];
            }
            if ($.isPlainObject(ret[name])) {
                ret[name][nameVal] = val;
            }
            else if($.isArray(ret[name])){
                ret[name].push(val);
            }
        }
    });
    return ret;
};
```

Then you can do: `$.parseQuery('param1=example&param2[]=value1&param2[]=value2');`.

Comment: is this possible to do this with just Javascript?  To parse the get string in this way?  The parameters are only used to query local data.  I effectively just use parameters to allow the user to bookmark filtered data

Comment: @CrimsonChin: Yes it is.  `window.location.search` contains the get string.  You can then parse it in JavaScript.  You can use this method I wrote: https://gist.github.com/3528917 :-)  (Note: `window.location.search` contains the `?`, you you'll need to call it like: `$.parseQuery(window.location.search.substring(1))`).

Comment: I don't have access to the query string - I think its a JQM thing, because of the # tag.  That being said, I can split the window.location.href to get the query string and your github code works excellently.  Could I suggest putting the code in your answer? I think its very valuable to the question/answer.  Its your code, so the choice is yours. Thanks either way

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to escape the pipe and commas in the user input before posting them to your url.

That means sanitising the user input values and replacing `|` and `,` with something that doesn't break your code or just stripping them altogether.

Comment: Problem is the values are query parameters and they need to match the data they are querying

Comment: You will need to have some kind of encoding/decoding on the way. Keep in mind ampersands will also break your array.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent casual tampering, you could add a checksum and base-64 encode your values then encodeURIComponent() the resulting string. (See [How can you encode to Base64 using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) and [A JavaScript CRC32](http://noteslog.com/post/crc32-for-javascript/).)

Of course, this won't prevent someone who's really determined from messing with your values, but it will slow down people who just like to twiddle URLs.

Answer (score -1):

When I think of serializing a list of key-value pairs, I immediately think of using a query-string.

For basics (JSON used to show deserialization):

```
foo=bar&foo=baz&fizz=buzz&alpha&beta=
```

is essentially:

```
{
    foo: [
        'bar',
        'baz'
    ],
    fizz: 'buzz',
    alpha: null,
    beta: ''
}
```

But special characters have to be escaped:

```
foo=bar%26baz
```

is essentially:

```
{
    foo: 'bar&baz'
}
```

What this means is that you can pass a query-string as a value in another query-string:

```
foo=bar%3Dbaz%26fizz%3Dbuzz
```

is essentially:

```
{
    foo: 'bar=baz&fizz=buzz'
}
```

And `foo` can be parsed to produce:

```
{
    bar: baz,
    fizz: buzz
}
```

---

That all being said, it's very easy to make mistakes while encoding/decoding, and as soon as you start double-encoding and double-decoding you're guaranteed to run into issues. If you can, use a single query string to contain all the necessary data, and don't embed a query-string within a query-string.